Unable to view the omniscript on the experience cloud page
When I am adding a LWC in an omniscript and placing the omniscript on the experience cloud site, I am not able to view the omniscript on the page. What could be the reason?
HTML:
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Book your appointment">
        <lightning-button variant="base" label="Click to book appointment" onclick={openbooking}></lightning-button>
        <template if:true={showbooking}>
            <iframe width="300px" height="400px" src={targetUrl}></iframe>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>

JS:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class bookingNavigation extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement) {

    showbooking=false;

    openbooking(){
        this.showbooking=true;
    }
    
    get targetUrl(){
        return 'https://abcd28-dev-ed.my.site.com';
    }

}
}

XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>62.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <runtimeNamespace>omnistudio</runtimeNamespace>
    <targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

Edit: Updated formatting

You forgot to add the import statement of omniscriptBaseMixin
Add this in your import statement on top. That should do the trick:
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from 'omnistudio/omniscriptBaseMixin';

